# javascript - decorate a class instance without explicitly forwarding all functions

Tags: javascript

Let me start by saying this is more of a curiosity question because, as you will see, I was able to achieve the desired functionality.
However, given that javascript is a super flexible language, I would like to see what other devs might think about this problem:

I have an instance of a class which is returned from a vendor function:

```
const connection = vendorDatabaseLib.createConnection();
```

Now, I would like to create a decorator which will add functionality to the connection class, for example, reconnection logic.
Lets call it `PersistentConnection`. Apart from my added custom functions I would like an instance of `PersistentConnection` to forward all function calls to the original `Connection` instance. And in some functions override the behaviour.
I could of course implement all `Connection`'s functions explicitly and forward them to the inner object but there might be lots of these functions, so I quickly discarded this idea.

So here are my ideas of how to achieve this:

1. Monkey patching , Instead of a decorator I can create a `PersistentConnection` class which inherits from the vendor `Connection` and then patch the vendor `vendorDatabaseLib.createConnection` function to return `PersistentConnection` with all my desired added functionality. Tempting, but bad.
2. Create a decorator which iterates over the `Connection` functions and creates forwards dynamically, something like:

```js
class PersistentConnection{
  constructor(connection){
     this._connection = connection;
     
     // Iterate through all functions
     for (prop in this._connection){
        if(typeof(this._connection[prop]) === 'function'){
          // Create functions dynamically for each forward
          this[prop] = (...args) => {
             this._connection[prop](...args);
          }
        }
     }
  }

  // This is the added logic
  reconnect(){
    // Custom logic
  }
}
```

3. Set the `Connection` **instance** to be a the prototype of `PersistentConnection`'s instance:

```js
function persistenChannel(channel){
  const persistentChannel = {};
  Object.setPrototypeOf(persistentChannel, channel);
  persistentChannel.reconnect = () => {
    // custom logic
  }
}
```

This is the most "automatic" way I could think of.. But it just down right ugly, and the custom functions need to be declared each time an instance is created.

I still feel like I'm missing something, something like Ruby's magical `method_missing` (or pythons `__getattr__`) function which is called just before a `method is missing` exception is thrown and lets you define "safety net" logic (like delegating all calls to the inner `_connection` object.
Is there a better way to achieve this functionality? 
Thanks a lot [=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start from what we have. In any case, most of the functionaliy will be performed by vendor object. We do not know details realization so we can't rely that this object has no state. This mean, that in any case we need **new** connection object for the new persistentConnection. This can be achieved with [proxy object](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler)

Lets try to do this:

```
function Connection() {
    this.connect = () => console.log('connected by Connection class');
    this.disconnect = () => console.log('disconnected by Connection class');
}


function persistantConnectionFactory() {
    function PersistentConnection() {
        this.checkConnection = () => console.log('no connection');
    }
    const instance = new PersistentConnection();
    const proxy = new Proxy(instance, {
        get: function (target, name) {
            if (!(name in target)) {
                console.log('adding new prototype')
                Object.setPrototypeOf(instance, new Connection())
            }

            return target[name];
        }
    });

    return proxy;
}

var c = persistantConnectionFactory();
c.checkConnection();
c.connect();
```

Does this solution good? I think - not. Without very good reasons this adds complexity without any value. Prototype should be enough.

Comment: Nice! Proxy is the missing link I was looking for!

Comment: @PavelTarno Feel free to mark as answer if it is an answer :)